# Play() Causes distortion/echo when playing sound

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am trying to make a chrome extension. Right now I have these codes:

```
 <button style="text-align:center; margin-bottom: 5px;" id="myboobutton">DogMeme.avi</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
```

The html that will be the button that plays a sound

I am making a button and giving it an id so it can call a Javascript file to play a sound (I have to do this because you can't run JS on the HTML of a chrome extension.) 
The button has an ID of 'myboobutton'

```
function myboo() {
var heyboosong = new Audio();
heyboosong.src = "myboo.mp3";
heyboosong.volume=0.5
heyboosong.play();
}

document.getElementById('myboobutton').addEventListener('click', myboo);
```

The button calls this popup.js so it can play the audio file.

I have a soundboard extension that plays various songs that are mp3s. When they play in the chrome extension they sound echoey. When the individual audio files play they sound fine. I suspect that it is making multiple calls to the function resulting in the echo. I am trying to figure out how to fix it. (thanks Makyen for helping to clarify) I've tested again and it still makes it.

It seems like all mp3 sounds seem to do this. Not sure if it is specific to chrome extensions or not. But it doesn't seem to happen on faster PCs as much. I am new to coding, I have just learned all of this in the past week. Thanks a bunch!

Here is the unpacked extension
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B3AU3p8wyWK3YXo1YUlGWGg5RGs?usp=sharing

Comment: You describe a single user click resulting in multiple calls to your `click` handler. Is that *really* what you intended to describe? This is very different than preventing the user from clicking the button multiple times within a short period. While some "solutions" might result in solving both situations, the former (single user click resulting in multiple calls to your function) is indicative of other issues/causes. The cause of the former will be somewhere else in your code. In order to determine what the issue is we would need a *complete* [mcve] which duplicates the problem.

Comment: I've just learned how to do all of these things during this week so please excuse me on this. Apologies. My thought is that this would fix my issue but it seems to be a problem with the Play function itself.

Comment: I changed it to be more clear now.

Comment: One thing that would be a good idea is to add a `console.log('Going to play audio')` to your event handler. You could then watch the console to see if your code gets called more than once (i.e. whatever you put in the `console.log()` gets output more than once). If your code gets called more than once when the problem occurs, then you know to investigate that. If it only gets called once, then you need to investigate what happens when you call `play()`. Without a *complete* [mcve] with which we can duplicate the problem, it is difficult to provide direct, specific advice to the problem.

Comment: I included the full unpacked extension if anyone can test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the button in the click event and create a setTimeout() function to enable the button again after a certain period of time.

For example:

```
var mybooBtn = document.getElementById('myboobutton');

mybooBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {      
  mybooBtn.disabled = true;
  setTimeout(function() { 
    mybooBtn.disabled = false;
  }, 1000);

  // code to play sound goes here
});
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g9wx30qj/

Comment: Presumably, the `play()` is asynchronous.  However, it would be better if you disabled the button and set the timeout immediately upon entering your function, prior to performing the other code.

Comment: yeah might not make a difference in this case, but in general it would be better, good call

Comment: Is there any alternatives to what I used? Because I basically have a soundboard that is filled with various songs that I want to play. A lot ofthe songs have echos, but not in the actual MP3 file, only on my extension. It's not every time that it happens.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the debounce/throttle concept. It is meant to be used when a function needs a delay between executions (i.e. ajax calls in typeahead plugins).

You can use a simple Throttle implementation:

```
var Throttle = function(fn, time) {
    var flag = true, toId;
    return function() { 
        if (flag) {
            var args = arguments;
            fn.apply(this, args);
            flag = false;
            clearTimeout(toId);
            toId = setTimeout(function() {
                flag = true;
            }, time);
        }        
    }  
};
```

And then, in your code:

```
document.getElementById('myboobutton').addEventListener('click', Throttle(myboo,1000)); //1000ms is 1second
```

Comment: Wow thanks! It worked to delay the button press which is want  I needed but it didn't seem to fix the echo. Hm I can't seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,do one thing;(I am showing a solution using jQuery)

```
$("#myboobutton").click(function(){

     $("#myboobutton").css("pointer-events","none");    //click 'll be disabled by this

    //write code for playing sound;

    setTimeout(function(){

        $("#myboobutton").css("pointer-events","");     //button 'll be clickable again after 1 sec
     },1000)
})
```